# html5 drag n drop divs with same id

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

i think the title is pretty self explanatory.
I have many divs generated from php code that take products from database.
the problem is when i drag them between two containers(also divs) i cant return all of them back to the first container because the products div id is same and it takes it as repeat from container 1 --> 2 and not backwards from contaner 2 --> 1.(2 containers have and all product divs have same id).
i can solve this by adding +1 to the divs id of the products(so they have different id) but that way i cant use the id from the css. Any solution?
here is the js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function allowDrop(ev){
                ev.preventDefault();
                }
            function drag(ev){
                ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
                }
            function drop(ev){
                if (ev.target.id == "container"){
                var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
                ev.preventDefault();
                }}
        </script>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not completely clear what your problem is?  Why do you need the `id` for the CSS?  Don't the products have a unique product number you can use for the ID?  Maybe it would help if you included a snippet of your markup in the question?  (Not all of it, just enough for us to see what it looks like)

Comment: Could you use the data- attribute instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved this by using incremented id for the div generated by php. how ever tha was not one of the solutions i wanted.
thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two divs with the same id. Try using classes.

Your `drop()` function should be something like this:

```
function drop(ev){
   if ( ev.hasClass('container') ) {
            // do some stuff
   }
}
```

You can add classes dynamically with jQuery `.addclass()` method.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'hasClass'
by the way i do not use jquerry, just pure js

Comment: if (ev.target.className.match(/\productDiv\b/)){
this works but still same behavior

Answer (score 1):

ID must be unique for the HTML to be valid. When you duplicate IDs, strange things happen. Even if you manage to get it working in one browser, others may handle things differently. You could try using classes instead.